# How would warriors know what astra is fired on them to counteract accordingly?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, war

In the epic wars like Ramayana and Mahabharata, How would warriors know what astra is being fired on them?

It is just a matter of time till the astra reaches the warrior. So, how would one anticipate what is invoked on them to invoke counter astra immediately?

Comment: Well, I suppose they could look at the Astra as it's being aimed by the other person.

Comment: How could they? When Astras are magical chantings which can be invoked using any arrow or even grass, How would one know what astra is invoked on them?

Comment: Well, in a worst case scenario where nothing else is available, then yeah, people would invoke the mantra on an ordinary arrow or a blade of grass.  But the Astras are also distinct arrow of their own, so the standard practice would be to actually use (say) a Brahmastra arrow rather than invoking the Brahmastra mantra on an ordinary arrow.  I think using Astra arrows may have been more effective then just using the Astra mantra.

Comment: So, one can trick others by chanting mantra of one astra and using different arrow??

Comment: Yeah, I suppose you could trick others by pretending to use an ordinary arrow but secretly using same Astra mantra.  But as I said, it may be less effective than using the original Astra arrow.

Comment: I think there are some changes in the environment for e.g. a nagpashastra might give some signs of snake hiss from akasha etc, so by closely meditating on the environment in yudhabhoomi (battlefield) one could easily know what is being fired and counteract.

Comment: @Keshav How (not to bother but) how do you know what was the method of launching astras?

Comment: @BharatG Well, with the usual descriptions, what happens is that one person fires the astra, and the thing starts displaying its powers as soon as it leaves. A trained warrior would recognize the characteristic features (I suppose) and immediately fires the counter astra. So there is enough time gap (in the pov of a great warrior) to gauge the enemy's astras.

Comment: @Surya I'm just going off of descriptions in Hindu scripture, like Rama using the Brahmastra and Arjuna using various Astras.

Comment: It is true that some astras can be invoked by using a blade of grass, but most of the time, the opponents will know what it is. Some astras can be known by seeing the tip of the arrow. There has been incidents when the opponent uses just any old Astra and it has "overcome" the Astra instead of countering it.